# Laravel 5.6 auth directive not working for some views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I was following a Laravel tutorial which was on 5.2 and I am using Laravel 5.6.29. I made two type of users, One is Admin and other is users. The problem I'm facing is that, when I'm logged in as admin, it is redirecting me to it's dashboard. And On the navigation bar, it is showing the username. But on some pages, such as homepage, blog pages, it is *still showing the Login and Register link in the navigation bar* and on some pages, like post creation, editing etc, it is *showing the name of logged in user*. How can I solve this problem so that the @auth is working on all the pages? Below are my files:

Route>web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();
Route::get('blog/{slug}', ['as' => 'blog.single', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getSingle'])->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
Route::get('blog', ['as' => 'blog.index', 'uses' => 'BlogController@getIndex']);
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@getAbout');
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@getIndex');
Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');
Route::get('/user/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@userLogout')->name('user.logout');


Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
});
```

AdminController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin');
    }
}
```

PostController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use App\Admin;
use Session;
use Purifier;
use Image;
use Storage;

class PostController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //the $posts variable stores all posts from DB
        $posts = Post::latest()->paginate(5);

        //return a view and pass abovr variable
        return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //validate the data
        $this->validate($request, array(    //validate() function is from extended class Controller
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'slug' => 'required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug',
            'author' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required',
            'featured_image' => 'sometimes|image'
        ));

        //Storing in the database
        $post = new Post;   //Creating new instance of post

        $post->title = $request->title; //Saves the title and body to $post
        $post->slug = $request->slug;
        $post->body = Purifier::clean($request->body);
        $post->author = $request->author;

        //save our image
        if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
          $image = $request->file('featured_image');
          $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
          Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);
          $post->image = $filename;
        }

        $post->save();          //Inserts the title and body to the DB

        $request->session()->flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully save!');

        //redirect to show page

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);           //finds the item by primary id and all the data retrieved from DB is stored in the $post variable
        return view('posts.show')->withPost($post); //the withPost helps to use the data of $post in our view by using $post
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.edit')->withPost($post);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

            $this->validate($request, array(
                'title' => 'required|max:255',
                'slug' => "required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:posts,slug,$id",
                'body' => 'required',
                'featured_image' => 'image'
            ));

        //save the data to the DB
    $post = Post::find($id);
        $post->title = $request->input('title'); //This means to grab the data from input with attribute 'title'
        $post->slug = $request->input('slug');
        $post->body = Purifier::clean($request->input('body'));

        if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
          //add the new photo
          $image = $request->file('featured_image');
          $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
          Image::make($image)->resize(800,400)->save($location);
          $oldFilename = $post->image;
          //update the database
          $post->image = $filename;
          //delete the old photo
          Storage::delete($oldFilename);
        }
        $post->save();

        //set flash data with success message
        $request->session()->flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully saved.');

        //redirect with flash data to posts.show
        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //delete the post
        $post = Post::find($id);

        $post->delete();

        Session::flash('success', 'The post has been successfully deleted.');
        return redirect()->route('posts.index');
    }
}
```

My navigation bar file- views>partials>_nav.blade.php:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/..">Laravel</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item {{Request::is('/')?"active" :""}}">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {{Request::is('blog')?"active" :""}}">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {{Request::is('about')?"active" :""}}">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item {{Request::is('contact')?"active" :""}}">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                    @auth
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                   onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                </a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}">
                                    {{ __('Dashboard') }}
                                </a>

                                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    @csrf
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        @else
                                          <li class="nav-item">
                                              <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li class="nav-item">
                                              <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                          </li>
                    @endauth
    </li>

  </ul>
</div><!--/.navbar-collapse-->
```

PagesController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Post;

class PagesController extends Controller{
    public function getIndex(){
        $posts = Post::latest()->limit(5)->get();
        return view('pages.welcome')->withPosts($posts);
    }

    public function getAbout(){

        return view('pages.about');
    }

    public function getContact(){
        return view('pages.contact');
    }
}
```

My main homepage: views>pages>main.blade.php:

```
@extends('main')

@section('title', '| Homepage')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1 class="display-4">Hello, world!</h1>
          <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
          <hr class="my-4">
          <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">

            @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="post">
                <h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ str_limit(strip_tags($post->body), 300) }}</p>
                <a href="{{url('blog/'.$post->slug)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
            </div>
            <hr>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
            <h3>Sidebar</h3>
            <a href="{{ route('admin.login') }}">Admin Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!--end of .row-->
@endsection
```

views>main.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
@include('partials._head')
</head>
<body>

  @include('partials._nav')

  <div class="container">

    @include('partials._messages')

        @yield('content')

    @include('partials._footer')

  </div><!--end of container-->

  @include('partials._javascripts')

</body>
</html>
```

When I login as admin, the The Login and Register link is replaced by my name in files in the auth folder in views (views>auth>{filesForLoggedInUsers}) but it displays Login and Register on all other views including welcome, blogs etc. Please help my what I'm missing.

Comment: define roles for admin and users.

Answer (score 0):

what did you set default config/auth.php 
did you try `@auth('admin')` ?

you can check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade)

Answer (score 0):

Specify the admin authentication guard to explicitly check the authentication for admin users.

```
@auth('admin')
<!--Your navigation items for admin users-->

@else
    @guest
       <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
        </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
       </li>
 @else
  <!--Your navigation items for general  users-->

  @endguest
  @endauth
```

Comment: it's not working, it is giving  me this error: `Trying to get property 'name' of non-object`.

Comment: have you used gaurd for authenticating admin users?